# Interrupting nested lists

Tags: lists, nesting

How to interrupt the nested lists and resume directly from the inner list?

For example:

Step 1: Define the below items

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Item Level 1
     \begin{enumerate}
          \item Item Level 2
     \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

Step 2: Define the comment in the first level:

```
comment at level 1
```

Step 3: Define the second item in the second level:

```
     \begin{enumerate}
          \item Item Level 2
     \end{enumerate}
```

Step 4: Define the comment in the second level:

```
    comment at level 2
```

Step 5: Define another comment in the first level:

```
comment at level 1
```

Step 6: Define the second item in the first level:

```
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
  \item Item Level 1
\end{enumerate}
```

Resuming the first level is achieved using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1356148/4836511). How to interrupt both first & second list and resuming directly from second list second item?

The Final expected output should be something like this:

```
1. Item Level 1
    a. Item Level 2
comment at level 1
    b. Item Level 2
    comment at level 2
comment at level 1
2. Item Level 1
```

Could you please suggest some ideas for this?

Comment: Will possible items  content be several lines long?

Comment: Possibly, yes, it contains!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, with the `series` key, for the level 2 enumerate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[wide=1em, leftmargin=*]
  \item Item Level 1
     \begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, series=level2]
          \item Item Level 2
     \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

Comment at level 1
 \begin{enumerate}[resume*]
 \item[]
 \begin{enumerate}[resume*=level2, wide = 0pt]
 \item Item Level 2
 \end{enumerate}
\noindent Comment at level 2
\end{enumerate}

Comment at level 1
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
 \item Item Level 1
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, Thanks. Would it be possible to have the level1 comments aligned with the numbers like the level2 alphabets?

Comment: es, it is: jus set `\parindent` to 1em (like `labelindent`), and make the comments for level 1  start a new paragraph. Please see the updated code. However, note that only the first line of the comment will be aligned with the level 1 label.